# Curly braces in visual studio running desktop parallels mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, curly-braces

I'm testing visual studio in desktop parallels win7 running on my Macbook air. Everything works fine except that i cannot get curly braces to work inside visual studio.

The Curly braces do work Shift + right-alt 7/8 (tested in notepad) but something is overriding the key combination inside visual studio.

software specs in parallels

Windows 7
Visual studio 2012
Resharper

I think it is Resharper that is messing with me. Does anyone know how to turn off a shortcut, specifically the key combination  shift + right-alt + 7/8   so i can get curly braces working again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check all the different shortcuts in Visual Studio and modify them as you like.

In Visual Studio goto: `Tools -> Customize` and press the `Keyboard` button at the bottom.
Then, in the **"Press Shortcut Key"** TextBox just press the key combination and you'll see what command it is set to, and you can remove/redefine that combination

Comment: Cheers :) It was that Resharper messing up keybindings

Comment: Awesome, I was experiencing the same issues with Parallels 8, Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012 and Resharper 8 beta.

Comment: Coolness! This also solves my problem that he closing brace would not work when running VS over Remote Desktop! (I need to press Ctrl+Alt on a german keyboard.)

Comment: Which command was it, mine cant do the curly brace in the IDE but can in the Press Keyboard Shorcut, so which resharper command was it? :)

Comment: For anyone coming here - It is the "Enable_Daemon" resharper command that exists on ctrl+shift+alt+8 which is option+shift+8 on mac.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I finally found how it work:
for { type right-alt+5 and for [ type right-alt+shift+5

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 the keyboard settings are at `Tools -> Options` under `Environment/Keyboard`.

I could not find the bound command by pressing the shortcut.

After some digging i discovered the command name: `ReSharper_EnableDaemon`. Removing all shortcuts for this command, I can now type `{` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **fn + alt (right alt key) + 7/8** in your keyboard. Should fix most of those Mac parallel issues.